# error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 16: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am trying to create a Kubernetes cronjob. During the deployment, I get this error:

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on
>   lemming-metrics/templates/lemming-metrics-cronjob.yaml: error
>   converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 16: mapping values are not allowed
>   in this context

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.lemming_metrics.kubeServiceAccount }}
          containers:
          - name: {{ .Values.name }}
            image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}
            tag: latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            resources: {{ toYaml .Values.resources }}
            args:
            - /usr/bin/python
            - /opt/lemming_metrics.py
            env:
            - name: REGIONS
              value: {{ .Values.lemming_metrics.regions}}
            - name: ECS_CLUSTER
              value: {{ .Values.lemming_metrics.ecs_cluster}}
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
    backoffLimit: 2
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 90
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Sees like you have copied this directly from a [Helm template](https://helm.sh/). Try starting with a sample cron job from Kubernetes docs. Helm templates have placeholders (all those {....} strings for example) which get replaced before deployment. This is not valid yaml til placeholders get replaced.

Comment: As @user6317694 mentioned values in {} will be mapped with values from other file. 
`Helm uses a packaging format called charts. A chart is a collection of files that describe a related set of Kubernetes resources.` If you want to use helm you have to use it proper. Please check [Helm guide](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#quickstart-guide). If you want to apply it using `kubectl` you have to write cronjob from [documenation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job).
Please provide more information if you are using HELM

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might need to fix the spacing for the indents (use 2 spaces). Otherwise, I've found that if you are incorrectly defining a service/pod/deployment, you can receive this error message (where specific line it points to in reality doesn't matter)